# Find the optimal pair of date ranges from a list determined by overlapping days

Tags: sql-server

I have data like below. What is an efficient SQL approach to finding the pair(s) of date ranges that maximize the amount of overlap among a set of start and end pairs.

```
     08/1/2020------------------01/15/2021
               12/1/2020-------------01/31/2021
                                               03/31/2021------------09/4/2021
```

[image]

Looking at the example above you can see that the "most overlapped" pair or longest stretch of common days is from 12/1/2020 through 01/15/2021 which is derived as the intersection of the top two. The number of pairs will not be known in advance.

The platform is SQL Server 2019 and the DDL is listed below. Each list of dates has the same id. The output should list the id value shared by that list of dates along with start and end dates that describe the maximal start and end. Input rows might not be distinct. Output rows should be distinct and all ties should be output as well.

```
create table portfoliodates
(id int, startdate date, enddate date) 

insert into portfoliodates
(id, startdate, enddate) 
values
 (8034, '08/01/2020', '01/15/2021'),
 (8034, '12/01/2020', '01/31/2021'),
 (8034, '03/31/2021', '09/04/2021'),
 (8035, '10/29/2021', '2022/05/31'),
 (8035, '10/01/2014', '9999/12/31')
```

**Input:**

| id | startdate | enddate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8034 | 08/01/2020 | 01/15/2021 |
| 8034 | 12/01/2020 | 01/31/2021 |
| 8034 | 03/31/2021 | 09/04/2021 |

**Expected output:**

| id | startdate | enddate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8034 | 12/01/2020 | 01/15/2021 |

**Input:**

| Id | startdate | enddate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8035 | 10/29/2021 | 2022/05/31 |
| 8035 | 10/01/2014 | 9999/12/31 |

**Expected output:**

| Id | startdate | enddate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8035 | 10/29/2021 | 05/31/2022 |

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Thank you for recommendations. I added some info as per your suggestions

Comment: You can copy ##1-4 to your question, and use them as section headers.

Comment: So far, you provided some junk. Table columns have mandatory data types. It shall be working T-SQL. And your logic is completely unclear.

Comment: I added column type. Sorry i am new to asking questions in stackoverflow. Which part you are not clear logic wise?

Comment: why is 1/31/2021 no covered?

Comment: Because if you compare the enddates 1/15/2021 is covered by 1/31/2021 but 1/31/2021 is not covered by any other enddate. So basically overlapping date from the list of the dates.

Comment: I don't understand the definition of "cover" here.

Comment: Cover meaning in the sense of  Overlap the dates here

Comment: 9/4/2021 makes 1/31/2021 overlap though

Comment: But we need to compare the whole range though. 1/31/2021 is not part of range 3/31/2021 to 9/4/2021.

Comment: `08/1/2020` to `1/15/2021` and `12/1/2020` to `1/31/2021` both overlap each other, why only the second must be returned?

Comment: i am trying to find intersection of date range here. if you see the screenshot i attached you can see see 12/1/2020 to 1/15/2020 is the most overlapped date range here.

Comment: See if i understood correct:  `08/1/2020 to 1/15/2021` has 167 days.  `12/1/2020 to 1/31/2021` has  61 days. These periods overlap by 45 days. As the second one is more overlaped (74%) than the other (26%) then the second one is returned. If the overlaping was equal, both would be returned?

Comment: Why did you delete and repost your question?

Comment: So i guess you can mix and match startdate and enddate . It doesn't need to be in the same sequence that it provided. If you see the screenshot, most overlapped area is from 12/1/2020 to 1/15/2021 . This area overlapped by the date range 8/1/2020 to 1/31/2021.

Comment: I mean mix the startdate with startdates list and enddate with enddates list anf find most overlapping range.

Comment: I asked this your previous deleted question. Will you have multiple rows of overlapping dates or are you expecting maximum 2 rows only

Comment: Multiple meaning this can happen. One date can be like this : 08/1/2020- 08/1/2022. So two other date ranges 12/1/2020-1/31/2021 and  3/31/2021- 9/4/2021 would be overlapped by 08/1/2020- 08/1/2022.

Comment: In this example which range will be returned? Because both are completely overlaped, 100% overlap.

Comment: In that case range returned will be this.12/1/2020 - 09/4/2021. Since this is the most overlapped range here.

Comment: Buddy, this request is meaningless.

Comment: what do you mean by meaningless. i am trying to solve problem . i had given appropriate table structure, expected output, screenshots. even people able to understand my request and able to give me solution as well. i am hoping that my request gets open so other devs can comment as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pair off all date ranges with a common id and find the ones that have
The longest stretch of common days. Ties are possible so handle those as necessary.

```
with overlap as (
    select p1.id, overlapdays, maxstart, minend,
        dense_rank() over (partition by p1.id order by overlapdays desc) as dr
    from portfoliodates p1 inner join portfoliodates p2
        on p2.id = p1.id and (
              p2.startdate > p1.startdate
           or p2.startdate = p1.startdate and p2.enddate > p1.enddate
        )
        cross apply (values (
          case when p1.startdate > p2.startdate then p1.startdate else p2.startdate end,
          case when p1.enddate   < p2.enddate   then p1.enddate   else p2.enddate   end
        )) v1(maxstart, minend)
        cross apply (values (datediff(day, maxstart, minend))) v2(overlapdays)
    where overlapdays >= 0
)
select * from overlap where dr = 1;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/LhgVL7z9

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using `inner join`.

```
select Id
      ,startdate    
      ,min(enddate)                    as enddate
from
       (
       select p.Id                     as Id
             ,p.startdate              as startdate
             ,p2.enddate               as enddate
             ,min(p2.startdate) over() as mnd
             ,max(p.enddate)    over() as mxd
       from   portfoliodates p  join portfoliodates p2 on p2.Id = p.Id 
       ) t
where         startdate > mnd
       and    enddate   < mxd
       and    startdate < enddate
group  by Id, startdate
```

| Id | startdate | enddate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8034 | 2020-12-01 00:00:00.000 | 2021-01-15 00:00:00.000 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2920b332b9f610396f2520a6d3ea7c6a&hide=1)

Comment: this works for 1st example but when i am trying with  these data  ('8034', '2021-10-29', '2022/05/31'),    ('8034', '10/1/2014', '9999/12/31'). it's not giving any result. it should give me overlapping range in this case it will be 2021/10/29 - 2022/05/31

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't think of another way to get the "most overlapped range", check if this crazy logic helps you

```
--############### SCHEMA #######################

Create table portfoliodates
(Id int, startdate datetime, enddate datetime) 

Insert into portfoliodates
(Id, startdate, enddate) 
values
(8034, '2020-07-03', '2020-08-05'),
(8034, '2020-08-03', '2020-08-07'),
(8034, '2021-02-01', '2021-08-04'),
(8034, '2020-08-01', '2021-01-15'),
(8034, '2020-12-01', '2021-01-31'),
(8034, '2021-03-31', '2021-09-04')

--################# QUERY #####################
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#PortfolioWithId') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #PortfolioWithId
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Intersections') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #Intersections

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) UniqueId, *
INTO #PortfolioWithId
FROM portfoliodates
WHERE id = 8034 --################### ID HERE #############

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IDX ON #PortfolioWithId(UniqueId)

CREATE TABLE #Intersections (id INT, startdate DATETIME, enddate DATETIME, overlapped_days INT)

DECLARE @Count INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #PortfolioWithId)
DECLARE @i INT = 0

WHILE @i <= @Count
BEGIN
    DECLARE @id INT, @startDate DATETIME, @endDate DATETIME
    
    SELECT @id = Id,
           @startDate = startdate,
           @endDate = enddate
    FROM #PortfolioWithId
    WHERE UniqueId = @i

    DECLARE @j INT = @i + 1

    WHILE @j <= @Count
    BEGIN       
        DECLARE @idAux INT, @startDateAux DATETIME, @endDateAux DATETIME

        SELECT @idAux = Id,
               @startDateAux = startdate,
               @endDateAux = enddate
        FROM #PortfolioWithId
        WHERE UniqueId = @j

        SET @j = @j + 1

        DECLARE @overlapedDays INT

        IF @startDate <= @startDateAux AND @endDate >= @startDateAux AND @endDateAux >= @endDate --## OVERLAP TYPE 1
        BEGIN
                 SET @overlapedDays = DATEDIFF(DAY, @startDateAux, @endDate) + 1 
            INSERT INTO #Intersections VALUES (@id, @startDateAux, @endDate, @overlapedDays)            
        END
        ELSE IF @startDateAux <= @startDate AND @endDate >= @endDateAux AND @endDateAux >= @startDate --## OVERLAP TYPE 2
        BEGIN
                 SET @overlapedDays = DATEDIFF(DAY, @startDate, @endDateAux) + 1 
            INSERT INTO #Intersections VALUES (@id, @startDate, @endDateAux, @overlapedDays)
        END             
        ELSE IF @startDate >= @startDateAux AND @endDate <= @endDateAux --## OVERLAP TYPE 3
        BEGIN
                 SET @overlapedDays = DATEDIFF(DAY, @startDate, @endDate) + 1 
            INSERT INTO #Intersections VALUES (@id, @startDate, @endDate, @overlapedDays)
        END             
        ELSE IF @startDateAux >= @startDate AND @endDateAux <= @endDate --## OVERLAP TYPE 4
        BEGIN
                 SET @overlapedDays = DATEDIFF(DAY, @startDateAux, @endDateAux) + 1 
            INSERT INTO #Intersections VALUES (@id, @startDateAux, @endDateAux, @overlapedDays)
        END     
    END 

    SET @i = @i + 1
END 

SELECT TOP 1 * FROM #Intersections ORDER BY overlapped_days DESC
```

Comment: this solution works perfect. thank you for that. but it's making performance very slow.it's taking long time to check each if . my records are only 10k and it's already 2 minutes and it's not able to load. it's just preety much hang at some point and i need to force shut down SSMS.

Comment: Hmm i will try think in a more efficient logic, because, with 10k rows, each row is compared to almost other row, so it will be almost 100M reads

Comment: ya it make sense with 100M read it's taking quite long to load. it will be great if you able to think more efficient logic but you got the intersection range as expected.

Comment: Is this something you will have to run frequently?

Comment: yes. running it often. when user click on the page we load the appropriate id with start date and enddate.

Comment: Can you tell more about the problem? Why do you need the "most overlapped range"? Why the user needs it?

Comment: that's something business want. they want to intersect the available dates for that id and show it to user.

Comment: so there are 10k records with that the same id?

Comment: no total 10k records. with different ids.

Comment: If you run the query for an specific ID, does it run faster? I added the ID 8034 for an example, what are the maxium rows an ID has?

Comment: ya i am trying with one particular id and it's faster. also i have id and another unique column as well if i want to group by with id and code . how can i do that?

Comment: You mean like this? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/aa718/1, if it's not send me sample data and expected result

Comment: I think you'll have better luck with this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8c721ffa539f68608b8fb53e6e741cab

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8c721ffa539f68608b8fb53e6e741cab this works like a charm. thank you so much @shawnt00.  this is really huge help.

Comment: @shawnt00 can you add this as your answer. I want to give you credit of this answer.